# how do i resolve, "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found"?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-ios-build

```
     In file included from /Users/shaifdihan/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:5:
    /Users/shaifdihan/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
/Users/shaifdihan/StudioProjects/my_match_flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'libPhoneNumber-iOS' from project 'Pods')
    .
    .
    .
```

did eyery possible solution that i could find on the internet to solve the issue

- pod deintegrate, install, update, repo update
- delete iOS folder, flutter create ., copy Runner folder
- flutter clean, flutter pub cache repair
- project built with 2.5.3, checked with 2.10.3 also

if i remove the webview_flutter plugin, sharedpreferences starts to show the same Flutter.h not found...then removed the sharedpreferences package, now Permission Handler package shows the same error!!

My Podfile

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
    
    # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
    ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
    
    project 'Runner', {
      'Debug' => :debug,
      'Profile' => :release,
      'Release' => :release,
    }
    
    def flutter_root
      generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
      unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
        raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
      end
    
      File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
        matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
        return matches[1].strip if matches
      end
      raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
    end
    
    require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)
    
    flutter_ios_podfile_setup
    
    target 'Runner' do
      use_frameworks!
      use_modular_headers!
    
      flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    end
    
    # post_install do |installer|
    #   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    #     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    #   end
    # end
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = "arm64 i386"
        end
      end
    end
```

flutter doctor -v

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.6.5 20G527 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Users/shaifdihan/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (6 months ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/shaifdihan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what i did was...

- Updated Xcode to latest
- change the minimum iOS version to 12 from Xcode/Runner/General/Deployment Info
- then, pod deintegrate, install, update, repo update
- flutter clean
- flutter pub get

this solved the issue

Comment: It didn't work for xcode 15 for Flutter. I got `'Flutter/Flutter.h' not found` issue. I event tried after downgrading but didn't work.

Comment: @c-an I have the same case like yours, did you find any solution?

Comment: @wahyu I think I upgraded flutter version.